# CMake: Don't set rpath for a single library used in link

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, ld

What I'd like to do is configure my CMakeLists file so that while building my project the linker uses a copy of a shared library (.so) that resides in my build tree to link the executable against but then does not set the rpath in the linked executable so that the system must provide the library when the loader requests it.

Specifically, I want to link against libOpenCL.so during build time on a build farm that doesn't have libOpenCL.so installed as a system library. To do this, libOpenCL.so is in the project build tree and referenced using an absolute path in the CMakeLists file. This absolute path is to ensure that if the system does happen to have libOpenCL.so installed then it is not used.

However, when running the final executable, CMake has added the absolute path to the rpath which stops the system version of libOpenCL.so being picked up by the library loader and used.

Seems simple but I can't quite figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You may take full control for RPATH settings instead of letting CMake to autogenerate it. See wiki about [handing RPATH in CMake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Comment: @Tsyvarev link is now https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Answer (score 6):

I know this answer is super late. I faced the same requirement as yours.
Either we need is whitelist approach where we set `CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH` explicitly with what we need. Or we need a blacklist approach where we tell cmake, which `RPATH`s we don't want in the executable. Way to remove `RPath` from build tree is not documented yet: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16825

The solution I took is:

Set `RUNPATH` instead of `RPATH`. You can achieve this by the statement:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--enable-new-dtags")
```

When `RUNPATH` is present, `RPATH` is ignored. 
`RUNPATH` - same as `RPATH`, but searched after `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, supported only on most recent UNIX

Then I can achieve the overriding the library using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [CMake Wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) this should not be a problem:

> By default if you don't change any RPATH related settings, CMake will link the executables and shared libraries with full RPATH to all used libraries in the build tree. When installing, it will clear the RPATH of these targets so they are installed with an empty RPATH.

So you might try to simply install it?

Comment: I'm wanting to modify the build tree rpath rather than the install rpath. In addition, some of the libraries I use are custom libraries that should have an rpath once installed. Getting the right mix to keep the rpath for some libraries and discarding it for others is the crux of my problem. Ideally, per library rpath configuration but I can;t find that in cmake :(

Comment: @user2746401 So are a compiling "in place" without installing of moving the final binaries somewhere else? Even if you would strip the rpath of all your binaries, the "temporary" OpenCL lib would still be the best match for the linker, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ToniBig I am building in place. If I strip the rpath the library loader won't be able to find my custom libraries at all so the loader would not find the "temporary" OpenCL library. Note this is a library loader question rather than a linker configuration question.