# Prevent CMake from adding the library export directory the the executable RPath

Tags: c++, cmake, rpath

I have a small project with a shared library and an executable. I specify the `rpath` to be `$ORIGIN/.` so that it is the same folder as the executable. When I make the program, it adds `/home/?????/test/lib/release` to it. The question marks are my name so I censored it. This is the same as my library output path. Is there a way to prevent CMake from adding this to the `rpath`? Here are both of my `CMakeLists.txt` files.

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/debug/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/release/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/debug/)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/release/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH $ORIGIN/.)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)
```

and

```
add_library(testlib SHARED inlib.cpp)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test testlib)
```

Comment: It seems CMake doesn't allow to set build RPATH **instead** of autogenerating it. You may either set build RPATH *in addition* to autogenerated one (as you do), or disable build rpath completely (`set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH TRUE)`). However, precise control over build RPATH is rarely needed: a **build tree** is **not movable**. If you want to distribute your executable to other machines (or to other places on build machine), you need to distribute **install tree**. In case of install tree CMake doesn't autogenerate RPATH and you have full control over it.

Comment: See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776048/cmake-dont-set-rpath-for-a-single-library-used-in-link), which is about things similar to yours.

Comment: IIRC, there is difference between installed binaries and the binaries from the `build` directory. CMake adds some RPATH's to the build products so you can run them right away, but removes them during `make install`.